# Velocity split() and array display, concatenate syntax

Tags: java, split, velocity, vte

I am trying to work with Velocity, which is like programming with your feet. I'm fluent in JavaScript and PHP but not Java. So I need a little help figuring out the correct syntax for this. I've done some research but since I'm not familiar with Java and Velocity is cringy, I can't figure out the right syntax.

I have a string, **$string** that is a url. I need to split it at the anchor # and reorganize it so that it will be in proper form for parameters and an anchor tag.

WHAT I HAVE:

URL ($string): **http://url.com#anchorlink**

PARAMETERS (plain text): **?utm_campaign=abc&utm_medium=def**

WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO:

Split the string at # and reconsitute the url to:

**http://url.com?utm_campaign=abc&utm_medium=def#anchorlink**

HERE'S WHAT I HAVE IN CODE that I need help putting into proper syntax (it's wrong here):

```
   <div>
    #set ($myArray = $string.split("#"));
        <a href = "${myArray[0]}?utm_campaign=abc&utm_medium=def${myArray[1]}">
            Link Text
        </a>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a `#` yourself after `def` in the URL as the value of `myArray` will be `{"http://url.com", "anchorlink"}`, without the `#` in either part. The below template should work:

```
<div>#set ($myArray = $string.split("#"))
        <a href = "${myArray[0]}?utm_campaign=abc&utm_medium=def#${myArray[1]}">
            Link Text
        </a>
</div>
```

The template returns the below result when I tested using `string=http://url.com#anchorlink` with a [tester](https://github.com/devatherock/velocity-template-tester) that I wrote:

```
<div>
        <a href = "http://url.com?utm_campaign=abc&utm_medium=def#anchorlink">
            Link Text
        </a>
</div>
```

You could get the same result also using below template, which uses `String.substring` instead of `split`:

```
<div>
        <a href = "${string.substring(0, $string.indexOf('#'))}?utm_campaign=abc&utm_medium=def${string.substring($string.indexOf('#'), $string.length())}">
            Link Text
        </a>
</div>
```